# Can we get the residuals from JAGS output?

Tags: bayesian, jags, r2jags

Say we fit a Bayesian linear mixed model using JAGS (or WinBUGS), does the output object include the model residuals? How can we find the residuals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JAGS (BUGS) model simply outputs the values of the nodes in the model you have told it to monitor. To get residuals you need to define those in the model and then monitor them. For example

```
model {
 bResponse ~ dnorm(0, 5^-2)
 sResponse ~ dunif(0, 5)
 for (i in 1:length(Response)) {
   eResponse[i] <- bResponse
   Response[i] ~ dlnorm(eResponse[i], sResponse^-2)
   Residual[i] <- (log(Response[i]) - log(eResponse[i])) / sResponse
 }
}
```

were `Residual[i]` defines a residual for each of the `i` values of the `Response`. Note the above example does not deal with specifying which values to monitor.